# Is knowing $P(A), P(A,B)$, and $P(A,C)$ sufficient to find $P(A \mid B,C)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

$A,B,C$ are possible values for the random variable $A', B', C'$ respectively. My intuition says no because you don't know if $B$ and $C$ are independent or not, and by Bayes' rule $P(A \mid B,C) = \frac{P(A, B, C)}{P(A, C)}$.

Is it possible to find $P(A , B , C)$ and $P(A , C)$ with just the information above?

Comment: what is P(A B)? That isn't standard notation.

Comment: It is a common shorthand to represent conjunction with product notation.  It is not encouraged but ... meh.

Comment: The notation I learned is P(A,B) - where A is a member of vector A' and B is a member of vector B'. P(A,B) is their joint probability.

Comment: With this comment you are making things worse. You should use standard notations.

Comment: Is it possible to find $P(A|B)$ from the given information?

Comment: @bof Yes I think you should be able to find P(A | B) but I don't understand how that helps

Comment: I think knowing why you think you can find $P(A|B)$ from the given information would help us to understand what you are confused about, so the we can better answer your question.

Comment: Did you really mean $$P(A\ |\ B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(A,C)}$$ or was that a typo for the correct formula $$P(A\ |\ B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}\ ?$$

Comment: Your comment is correct. I am assuming you can find  P(A| B) because you know all P(A, B) for events in A' and B'.

Comment: Assuming you really believe that $$P(A\ |\ B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(A,C)}$$ then I guess you also believe that $$P(A\ |\ C,B)=\frac{P(A,C,B)}{P(A,B)}.$$ Therefore, if we suppose that $$P(A,B,C)=P(A,C,B)\text{ while }P(A,C)\ne P(A,B)$$ then we would have $$P(A\ |\ B,C)\ne P(A\ |\ C,B),$$ is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be iid Bernoulli $1/2$ r.v. s, and let $Y_1, Y_2$ be iid Bernoulli 1/2 random variables, and let $Y_3 = Y_1 \oplus Y_2$ (XOR addition)

Here, you can check that all the pairwise pmf s of $X$s and $Y$s are the same, but their mutual pmf is different.